# ios write geotag into image

Tags: objective-c, ios, jpeg, exif, geotagging

I need to read a jpg image *(not from the imagelibrary)* and write into them the exif geotag data taken from the iPhone gps
how can I do this?

thanks in advance.

Paolo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIImagePickerController doesn't give you the Camera's location. You have to add CLLocationManager in the app. Initiate/delegate to self. And call "startUpdatingLocation". Then in "-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation", you are able to get your location from "newLocation".

Now if you want to save the image to photo Library, you can use https://github.com/gpambrozio/GusUtils

More explanations can be found: http://blog.codecropper.com/2011/05/adding-metadata-to-ios-images-the-easy-way/

Comment: How to add geotag to video file i.e. .mov or .mp4?

Comment: As far as I know, we cannot store the location information into .mov or .mp4 video files. Instead, "XMP" is used.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that such a class does not exist yet. If you know Perl a bit, get ExifTool and read the source, it's not that hard (read the jpg as binary, insert the exif tags for geotag and write it back (the file will grow some bytes only).

Comment: No, you need to write it in objective-c, use the perl-source as a guide.